# PostgreSQL functions and triggers

Tags: function, postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers, return

I am trying out functions and triggers int postgreSQL, however i am having a problem, when the function is triggered it is giving me an error

ERROR:  control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN

this particular procedure is only executing an insert into command so i do not see why it needs a return

this is the script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION forest_aud_func() returns trigger as $tree_stamp$ 
BEGIN
    insert into Audit values('k',124,'l');
END;
$tree_stamp$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create trigger forest_aud_ins after insert on forest
for each row execute procedure forest_aud_func()

insert into forest values('Blue',1600,'Malta','Health Ltd')
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error message tells you all. You need to do a RETURN from the trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION forest_aud_func() returns trigger as $tree_stamp$ 
BEGIN
    insert into Audit values('k',124,'l');
    return new;
END;
$tree_stamp$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

From [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html):

*A trigger function must return either NULL or a record/row value having exactly the structure of the table the trigger was fired for.*

Comment: ok thanks, did as you said, now its giving me this error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "audit_pk"
DETAIL:  Key (au_code)=(124) already exists.

i cheked in the table and 124 does not already exist

any ideas?

Comment: @Karl: Apparently you have a primary key on the `audit` table that you violate when inserting the audit values. That problem has nothing to do with writing the trigger.

Comment: insert into forest values('Blue',1600,'Malta','Health Ltd') is what i am inserting, which should result in a trigger insert of insert into Audit values('k',124,'l');

Comment: if i do the insert normally, it works fine, but through the trigger it keeps giving me that error...hmmm

Comment: @Karl: That PK problem is something else and probably should be a different question. As an aside, you really should be specifying the columns (`insert into audit (...) values (...)`) when using INSERT.

Comment: @mu is too short: I removed the primary key constraint and found out that with the above trigger it was entering it twice, i changed the trigger from 'for each row' to 'for each statement' and it entered it 3 times, im new to triggers so if you have any idea why this could be happening please advise, and yes you are right about the insert.

Comment: @Karl: Best to start a new question to give us more space and to get more eyeballs on the problem. The trigger should only be executed once for each row inserted when you use FOR EACH ROW so there is some confusion somewhere.

Comment: Does it matter what you return from a trigger function? Will this effect the outcome of the INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE command, or can you just return null from all trigger functions?

Comment: @CameronMartin: this is explained in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html